In the standard VB.Net toolstrip, can anyone tell me where the code for total number if items is
In the VB.Net standard navigation tool strip, can anyone tell me where the code for the totalnumberofitems is located. I want to use this number, to add 1 to it and increase the ID (Primary Key) textbox when I add a new record? This is a workaround for adding a new row to the SQL Table dynamically.

Most database systems have in-built functionality for providing sequence values automatically. Is there a reason you think you're going to do a better job than the database (especially if/when you start dealing with concurrent inserts from multiple users)?

Based on this question and the previous one, it seems you're confusing the navigation indices (what the BindingNavigator displays) and the database unique PK. The navigator displays the index of the current BindingSource record along with the records count. You don't need to do what you're asking for if you have the right setup which we don't know anything about it. The db PK field? The InsertCommand, UpdateCommand? Strongly-Typed data objects (DataSet, DataTable..) or are you creating them by code?

It's a very bad workaround and should not be implemented. You should actually solve the other issue, not implement a hack that could introduce other issues. I have commented on your other question so you should address that to find an actual solution to the actual problem.

If you really were going to do this, which you absolutely should not, then the BindingNavigator (that's the name of the thing, which doesn't appear anywhere in this question) is irrelevant. What you would be interested in would be the Count property of the BindingSource, which is what the BindingNavigator displays. That would pe problematic if your BindingSource is filtered though, in which case you'd have to use the Rows.Count of the DataTable that's still a problem if you haven't retrieved all records from the database though.

Note that, if you are using a database, it's the database that actually generates the final ID to be stored. The value generated by the DataTable is only temporary. It may end up being the same as the final value but it doesn't have to be.

Thanks, yeah it's something I've done so far no doubts. I'll make a fresh form and SQL table. Thanks for everything, much appreciated
